# Schema Exception Hibernate One to Many

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to do a simple One To Many relationship using Hibernate. Idea is that one Order can have many Order items. I am not sure why am I getting this exception. I am fairly new to Hibernate object relationships. Could you please point out if there is any configuration problem with this program. If you let me know how to do a this sort of mappings in hibernate, that would be great. Thank you!

**Order**

```
package one_to_many;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int order_id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;

    public Order() {

    }

    public Order(String name, String address, List<OrderItem> orderItems) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.orderItems = orderItems;
    }

    public int getOrder_id() {
        return order_id;
    }

    public void setOrder_id(int order_id) {
        this.order_id = order_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public List<OrderItem> getOrderItems() {
        return orderItems;
    }

    public void setOrderItems(List<OrderItem> orderItems) {
        this.orderItems = orderItems;
    }

}
```

**OrderItem**

```
package one_to_many;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int orderItemId;
    private String itemName;
    private int quantity;

    public int getOrderItemId() {
        return orderItemId;
    }

    public void setOrderItemId(int orderItemId) {
        this.orderItemId = orderItemId;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public OrderItem() {

    }

    public OrderItem(String itemName, int quantity) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderItem [orderItemId=" + orderItemId + ", itemName=" + itemName + ", quantity=" + quantity + "]";
    }

}
```

**Runner**

```
package one_to_many;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("/one_to_many/hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<OrderItem> list = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

        list.add(new OrderItem("book", 2));
        list.add(new OrderItem("tshirt", 4));

        Order order = new Order("regular", "919 Ridge", list);

        session.save(order);

        session.close();
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: Order
Hibernate: 
    create table Order (
        order_id integer not null auto_increment,
        address varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (order_id)


      )
Aug 11, 2016 9:45:40 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [
        create table Order (
            order_id integer not null auto_increment,
            address varchar(255),
            name varchar(255),
            primary key (order_id)

    )]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [
    create table Order (
        order_id integer not null auto_increment,
        address varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (order_id)
    )]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:557)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.createTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.performMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:723)
    at one_to_many.Runner.main(Runner.java:15)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (
        order_id integer not null auto_increment,
        address varcha' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:686)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2041)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1994)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:890)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:788)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
    ... 13 more

Aug 11, 2016 9:45:40 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl processGetTableResults
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: Order
Aug 11, 2016 9:45:40 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl processGetTableResults
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: Order
Aug 11, 2016 9:45:40 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl processGetTableResults
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: Order
Aug 11, 2016 9:45:40 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl processGetTableResults
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: Order
Hibernate: 
    alter table OrderItem 
        add constraint FK1d77ns82kvwa2hwab9k7xcaog 
        foreign key (order_id) 
        references Order (order_id)
Aug 11, 2016 9:45:40 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [
    alter table OrderItem 
        add constraint FK1d77ns82kvwa2hwab9k7xcaog 
        foreign key (order_id) 
        references Order (order_id)]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [
    alter table OrderItem 
        add constraint FK1d77ns82kvwa2hwab9k7xcaog 
        foreign key (order_id) 
        references Order (order_id)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:557)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applyForeignKeys(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:516)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.performMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:723)
    at one_to_many.Runner.main(Runner.java:15)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (order_id)' at line 4
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:686)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2041)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1994)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:890)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:788)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into

    Order (address
    , name) 
values
    (?, ?)
Aug 11, 2016 9:45:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
Aug 11, 2016 9:45:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (address, name) values ('919 Ridge', 'regular')' at line 1
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2840)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3411)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:668)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:660)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:655)
    at one_to_many.Runner.main(Runner.java:26)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (address, name) values ('919 Ridge', 'regular')' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:686)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2041)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1827)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2041)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1977)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:4963)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Your problem is that your table in the database doesn't have the name order. Which stands right there in the first line of your stack trace. To what table do you want to map it? In your case you want to use the `@Table` annotation. You should take a look at [Java Persistence Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence). That is a good introduction to JPA.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take a look at it, it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name 'order' is a Reserved Keywords in mysql. Change the table name 'order'.